# Выборка данных SQL в которой показатели для одной организации превышают показатели для другой организации

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

У нас есть таблица **companies**, состоящая из разных компаний **'comp_name'**, номеров карт клиентов **'card_id'** и сколько раз они совершали покупку **'count_buy'**.

ВОПРОС следующий, как написать ***SQL*** запрос и выбрать **'card_id'** только тех клиентов, у которых **количество покупок 'count_buy'** в условной ***"Пятёрочке"*****('comp_name')**, больше чем количество покупок в условном ***"Магнит"*** ???

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Посчитать по отдельности, сравнить, оставить только соответствующее условию. JOIN, GROUP BY, SUM(CASE), HAVING.